# How to write to / delete from external SD Card on Android 6.0 Marshmellow Huawei P9

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, security, external-sd

I'm coming from a rooted Samsung S4 to a non-rooted Huawei P9. With the rooted S4 I could do anything at all, the stock P9 is extremely restricted. I want to stay with stock because it's a phone that's been loaned to me and I don't want to risk breaking it, and I'd like the Android 7.x over the air update in a few months without having to unroot.

I would prefer not to mount the external SD as internal memory, as it's slower. I've tried creating files, deleting files, and changing permissions, I can't do anything.

Basically I would like to be able to do two things:

- Add and delete files to the external SD card using a file manager,
  such as Root Browser
- Have Bittorrent Sync (or other apps) write to the external SD card

I know Android security was ramped up around Android 5, but this much restriction is crazy. Is there a way around to do this working within the stock OS? I may just have to give up on external SD, it seems pointless to have it right now.

Comment: Android 5 had more restrictive SD Card permissions. Android 6 lowered those again. Newer applications like updated file explorers shoud automatically ask you for SD Card permission after the first start.

Did you try to install a file manager and see if it asks you for SD Card write permissions?

Comment: Thanks @Underlines. I tend to use Root Browser, which probably assumes you have root so doesn't ask for permissions. I've used ES in the past, but I found it annoying. Can you recommend a file browser that you know works with external SD on Marshmellow?

Comment: try Solid Explorer